# Junit report test result is displayed blank

Tags: eclipse, ant, selenium-webdriver, junit4

whenever i execute build.xml for first instant, generated report is blank. Now when i again execute the same build.xml for second time, it displays the timestamp of previous run.
Can anyone help me in understanding this situation

Build.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- WARNING: Eclipse auto-generated file.
          Any modifications will be overwritten.
          To include a user specific buildfile here, simply create one in the same
          directory with the processing instruction <?eclipse.ant.import?>
          as the first entry and export the buildfile again. -->
<project basedir="." default="build" name="test">
<property environment="env"/>
<property name="ECLIPSE_HOME" value="C:/Users/Downloads/eclipse"/>
<property name="junit.output.dir" value="junit"/>
<property name="debuglevel" value="source,lines,vars"/>
<property name="target" value="1.6"/>
<property name="source" value="1.6"/>
<path id="test.classpath">
    <pathelement location="bin"/>
    <pathelement location="../lib/junit-4.11.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../lib/jxl-2.6.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../lib/selenium-java-client-driver-1.0.2.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../lib/selenium-server-standalone-2.31.0.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="../lib/xalan-2.7.1.jar"/>
    <pathelement location="C:/Users/Downloads/eclipse/plugins/org.apache.ant_1.7.1.v20090120-1145/lib/ant-junit.jar"/>
</path>
<target name="init">
    <mkdir dir="bin"/>
    <mkdir dir="build/classes" />
    <mkdir dir="dist"/>
</target>
<target name ="compile" depends="init">
<javac srcdir="src" destdir="build/classes"/>
</target>
<target name ="jar" depends="compile">
    <jar destfile="dist/test.jar" basedir="build/classes" />
</target>
<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="bin"/>
    <delete dir="dist" />
</target>
<target depends="clean" name="cleanall"/>
<target depends="build-subprojects,build-project" name="build"/>
<target name="build-subprojects"/>
<target depends="init" name="build-project">
    <echo message="${ant.project.name}: ${ant.file}"/>
    <javac debug="true" debuglevel="${debuglevel}" destdir="bin" source="${source}" target="${target}" includeantruntime="false">
        <src path="src"/>
        <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>
    </javac>
</target>
<target description="Build all projects which reference this project. Useful to propagate changes." name="build-refprojects"/>
<target description="copy Eclipse compiler jars to ant lib directory" name="init-eclipse-compiler">
    <copy todir="${ant.library.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </copy>
    <unzip dest="${ant.library.dir}">
        <patternset includes="jdtCompilerAdapter.jar"/>
        <fileset dir="${ECLIPSE_HOME}/plugins" includes="org.eclipse.jdt.core_*.jar"/>
    </unzip>
</target>
<target description="compile project with Eclipse compiler" name="build-eclipse-compiler">
    <property name="build.compiler" value="org.eclipse.jdt.core.JDTCompilerAdapter"/>
    <antcall target="build"/>
</target>
<target name="test">
    <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
    <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
        <formatter type="xml"/>
        <test name="AllTests" todir="${junit.output.dir}/Project"/>
        <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>
    </junit>
</target>
<target name="junitreport">
    <junitreport todir="${junit.output.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
        </fileset>
        <report format="frames" todir="${junit.output.dir}/Project"/>
    </junitreport>
</target>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your targets aren't being run in the desired order.  You really should have the dependencies specified in the Ant task itself.  For example, I've added the fact that unitreport depends on test in this example.

```
    <target name="test">
        <mkdir dir="${junit.output.dir}"/>
        <junit fork="yes" printsummary="withOutAndErr">
            <formatter type="xml"/>
            <test name="AllTests" todir="${junit.output.dir}/Project"/>
            <classpath refid="test.classpath"/>
        </junit>
    </target>
    <target name="junitreport" depends="test">
        <junitreport todir="${junit.output.dir}">
            <fileset dir="${junit.output.dir}">
                <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
            </fileset>
            <report format="frames" todir="${junit.output.dir}/Project"/>
        </junitreport>
    </target>
</project>
```

Comment: Ok, well i am new to create such junit report and will try this snippet. :)

Comment: Jeanne :i tried this snippet, thanks it executes well. But now it executes the tests twice and displays the timestamp of second execution and thats an issue

Comment: How are you running Ant?  What command are you using?  (that will show what targets you are running)

Comment: Jeanne: I execute ant through command prompt and from eclipse. Command : ant -f build.xml test

Comment: That's odd.  The command you are running shouldn't be creating the junit report at all.  Are you sure it isn't "ant -f build.xml test junitreport" ?

Comment: Whoopss...my mistake, sorry. Command which i used was. Command : ant -f build.xml junitreport